# $.ajaxSetup global data doesnt merge in load function

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I would like to set a global data parameter for all my ajax requests

```
$.ajaxSetup({
   data: {hash : "12345"}
});
```

after setting this I call:

```
var myData = {
    name : "John",
    age : "28"
}

$.get(url, myData, function(data){
    ...
});
```

this works fine and add all 3 parameters (hash, name, age) to request data
but when I call load function instead of get, it doesnt work and I get only 2 parameters (name, age):

```
$("#my_div").load(url, myData, function(data){
    ...
});
```

please could anyone tell me why it doesnt work for load function? I have many usages of load function in my app and I dont want to change load on get

thank you for every tip!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could be considered a bug in jQuery; or at the very least, they should accept the interface between their AJAX methods are inconsistent.

The only way to fix this is by using `jQuery.extend` to merge the default `data` with the `data` you've provided:

```
jQuery.extend(myData, jQuery.ajaxSettings);
```

Before making the request.

**How its a bug:**

`load` [converts](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/f567a7fcfc9bd963142e6bb4fcf7923cacb582f1/src/ajax.js#L186) the `data` object into a string **before** passing in onto the underlying `jQuery.ajax` method, where as `get` [doesn't](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/f567a7fcfc9bd963142e6bb4fcf7923cacb582f1/src/ajax.js#L280).

Because of this, when [`ajaxExtend`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/f567a7fcfc9bd963142e6bb4fcf7923cacb582f1/src/ajax.js#L144) builds the `data` object, in the `load` scenario the `data` parameter is set to the string, whereas with `get` the `data` object is *merged* with `jQuery.ajaxSettings`.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at `.load`, you'll see it does not pass an object to `.ajax`, even if you pass one to `.load`:

```
    if ( params ) {

        ...

        } else if ( typeof params === "object" ) {

            // it will execute this

            params = jQuery.param( params, jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional );
```

It will call `jQuery.params`, which returns a **string**, and the object cannot be merged with the string. So it will send `"name=John&age=28"` without combining the hash object.

This is not the case for `$.get`, because that function directly passes the object:

```
jQuery.each( [ "get", "post" ], function( i, method ) {
    jQuery[ method ] = function( url, data, callback, type ) {

        ...

        return jQuery.ajax({
            type: method,
            url: url,
            data: data,         // passed directly to $.ajax which takes care of merging $.ajaxSetup stuff
            success: callback,
            dataType: type
        });
    };
});
```