# Add additional parameter to get/post ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, post, get

Is it possible to add some additional parameters to get/post methods in jQuery .

Ex :

```
$.get(url,{a:b,c:d},function(data){

//codes..

});
```

Here you can see that it contains two parameters, a and c.

Now think i need to add an additional parameter `[e:f]` to every get/post methods in a web page.

is this possible ?

So when we trigger a get/post method it need automatically add a additional parameter .

Thank you .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`jQuery.ajaxSetup()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/) to set defaults.

```
jQuery.ajaxSetup({
    data: {
        e: f // obviously `f` needs to be defined in this scope
    }
});
```

However, you should be aware that these parameters will *not* be included if you use `.load()`, due to what is most likely a [bug in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7805854/ajaxsetup-global-data-doesnt-merge-in-load-function).